# Print Nested Dictonary in PowerShell (Convert it to CSV)

Tags: powershell, csv, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary, one dictionary also includes a dictionary.

- How can I write them pretty format and convert it
  to CSV table. (with forloop & foreach via keys)

```
$testHashMap = @{
    'feature1' = @{
        'Audit'  = 1
        'Space'  = 2
        'Usage' = 3
    }
    'feature2' = @{
        'Audit'  = 4
        'Space'  = 5
        'Usage' = 3
    }
}

**Expected Output:**

        feature1  | feature2 
------------------|----------------
audit:     1      |   4
space:     2      |   5
usage:     3      |   3
```

Comment: Please provide your code and what you tried to achieve this output

Comment: Your expected output isn't in CSV format, given that the format doesn't support labels distinguishing individual rows, such as `audit:`

Answer (score 0):

Your sample (expected) table structure is not valid for the PowerShell table format.

Though below is the simplest solution you can try:

```
$testHashMap = [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
    'feature1' = [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
        'Audit'  = 1
        'Space'  = 2
        'Usage' = 3
    };
    'feature2' = [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
        'Audit'  = 4
        'Space'  = 5
        'Usage' = 3
    };
}
```

This will give you a tested table output like:

```
feature1                     feature2                    
--------                     --------                    
@{Audit=1; Space=2; Usage=3} @{Audit=4; Space=5; Usage=3}
```

If you want to show the feature name in the table, you can introduce a new column as given below:

```
($testHashMap | gm -MemberType NoteProperty).Name | %{ $FeatureName = $_; Select-Object -InputObject $testHashMap -ExpandProperty $_ -Property @{Name="FeatureName"; e={$FeatureName}} }
```

This will give the output like:

```
Audit Space Usage FeatureName
----- ----- ----- -----------
    1     2     3 feature1   
    4     5     3 feature2
```

Comment: As an aside: you don't need the `[Ordered]`: `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` - despite the seeming use of an unordered hashtable - is _syntactic sugar_ that automatically preserves the entry-definition order.